# google maps api findplace request not working properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, location

I want to display on my webpage the location from a JSON that has displayed a pharmacy name. The point is that google maps API is a little bit over my power of knowledge. I did a find-place request into the google maps API, but the location that is displayed is the one from my current location.

**Here is the part of the code that would interest you**

```
<div id="map"></div>

  <script src="./keys.js"></script>
  <script>
    let map;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      let s = document.createElement("script");
      document.head.appendChild(s);
      s.addEventListener("load", () => 
      {
        console.log("script has loaded");

        x = navigator.geolocation;

        x.getCurrentPosition(success, failure)

        function success(position){

          var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
          var myLong = position.coords.longitude;

          var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
      
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
              center: coords,
              zoom: 16,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: coords,
          })
        }
        
        function failure(){}          
        
      });
      s.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=<%= "#{@medicament['farmacies'].first['name']}"%>&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=**************`;
  
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

where `<%= "#{@medicament['farmacies'].first['name']}"%>` represents the name of the pharmacy from the html erb file.

**What I found strange is that if I inspect the page where the location is the `s.src` takes me to a JSON that has all the right address information for the pharmacy.**

Here you can see an image with the response from the API:

[image]

What I want is to point to the address of that pharmacy on google map. Any tips&tricks are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use [google.maps.places.PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.findPlaceFromQuery)instead.

Also see this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_from_query).

```js
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService();
  var request = {
    query: 'Museum of Contemporary Art Australia',
    fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
  };
  const {results} = service.findPlaceFromQuery(request);
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BQdAZQB.png is here something that I did wrong here? Is not showing anything on the map

Comment: Actually what I really want to display into the app is the closest pharmacy named 'x' from the current location of the user

Comment: Hello Justin, I am having one doubt. I am having one address string, which is working fine in google map, but same string is not working  in your above code. Maximum address strings are working for me, it's just, facing issue for few address string. Can you tell me why it is happening?